# change datepicker date with a previous chosen date in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Trying to change the Date on the Datepicker by binding it through a property.
If I set to DateTime.Now value. then it works. But I want to set to a previously chosen date if I blank the datepicker field and lose the focus.

```
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _previousChosenDateTime = Smilefjestilsyn.Dato;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _previousChosenDateTime = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The XAML code.

```
   <DatePicker Style="{StaticResource TabSkipableDatePicker}" 
                        Margin="-8,8,0,0" 
                        Background="Transparent" 
                        BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                        SelectedDate="{Binding Date, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        Grid.Row="6" 
                        Grid.Column="2"/>
```

Comment: First add INotifyPropertyChanged implementation to the Date property.

Answer (score 0):

1st: return _previousChosenDateTime = Smilefjestilsyn.Dato; always return Smilefjestilsyn.Dato all the time so you might want to change that.

Afterall, I believe the main problem that you are having is the "display" of DatePicker when the user explicitly remove everything in the textbox and the watermark "Select a date" appear instead of the desire "perivousdate". You might need to bind the "Text" property of the DatePicker in order to get that right

The following should work but I'm wondering if there's better solution. it's kinda ugly

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly DateTime _somePreviousDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);

    private DateTime? _startDateSelected;
    public DateTime? StartDateSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _startDateSelected.HasValue ? _startDateSelected : _somePreviousDate;
        }
        set
        {
            _startDateSelected = value.HasValue ? value : _somePreviousDate;

            OnPropertyChanged("StartDateSelected");
            OnPropertyChanged("StartDateSelectedString");
        }
    }

    public string StartDateSelectedString
    {
        get { return StartDateSelected.ToString(); }
    }
}


        <DatePicker Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" 
                    SelectedDate="{Binding StartDateSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Text="{Binding StartDateSelectedString}">
        </DatePicker>
```